# How to filter logs between a time range

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, grep

Here's my log format(simplified for demonstrating)

```
2018-04-12 14:43:00.000 ERROR hello
2018-04-12 14:44:01.000 ERROR world
2018-04-12 14:44:03.000 INFO this is a multi-line log
NOTICE THIS LINE, this line is also part of the log
2018-04-12 14:46:00.000 INFO foo
```

So how to filter the log of `[2018-04-12 14:44:00.000, 2018-04-12 14:45:00.000)` to produce the following output?

```
2018-04-12 14:44:01.000 ERROR world
2018-04-12 14:44:03.000 INFO this is a multi-line log
NOTICE THIS LINE, this line is also part of the log
```

Comment: So you're trying to get the log between a minute `14:44:00.000` and `14:45:00.000`. Then I guess between that time, there are countless number of lines that will be produce right?`

Comment: @WashichawbachaW yes exactly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `awk`:

```
awk -v 'start=2018-04-12 14:44:00.000' -v end='2018-04-12 14:45:00.000' '
   /^[[:digit:]]{4}-[[:digit:]]{2}-[[:digit:]]{2} / {
     inrange = $0 >= start && $0 <= end
   }
   inrange' < your-file
```

It won't work with `mawk` which doesn't support POSIX character classes nor interval regexp operators.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want particular lines between a certain time then `awk` will work. To give a slight tutorial

To start with and find out which lines you want:

`cat -n logfile`

That will show the contents of the file with the line numbers.

To print out the line numbers that you want:

`awk 'NR==2,NR==4' logfile`

That prints out the range between lines 2 and 4.

If you want to print out two ore more lines or a range of lines that aren't consecutive in case you want that then you can separate them with either `||` or `;`

`awk 'NR==5,NR==10;NR==15,NR==20' logfile`

Moving on to printing the lines between a certain time range, combine the above with grep `egrep`:

```
egrep "2018-04-12 14:44:01.000|2018-04-12 14:46:00.000" logfile | awk NR==5,NR==10
```

`egrep` allows multiple strings to be returned. The `|` symbol separates each string. That will print the lines with the start and end of the time range (I changed the end to a later time to include more lines) along with their line number. You can then use `awk` to print the range between and including the two lines.

You can take all of this as an example and modify it to suit your needs for your log files and what you want to print out according to the times.

Comment: Note: this does not work if the start or end range is not in the file

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar Problem currently , but **the "simple" sed/awk way failed when there are no logs for a minute** ( e.g.  idle routers )

Finally generated a **grep** statement for the last n minutes like this:

```
searchterms() {
  backlog_minutes=15;
  for searchstamp in $(seq 0 60 $((60*backlog_minutes)));do
   LANG=en_US.UTF-8 date "+%b %d %H:%M" -d @"$(($(date +%s)-$searchstamp))";done ;
  } ;
greptarget=$(searchterms|sed 's/^/-e "/g;s/$/"/g' )

##Openwrt
which logread |grep -q logread && ( grepcmd=$(echo  grep  "$greptarget"); echo "logread|$(echo $grepcmd)"|sh )
## Linux Debian/Ubuntu
which logread |grep -q logread || (echo grep -e $greptarget /var/log/syslog|sh ;exit 0)
```

---

what i tried before ( https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/437445/374376 )

```
##_date_syslog_15_min() { LANG=en_US.UTF-8 date "+%b %d %H:%M" -d "15 min ago"   ; } ;
##_date_syslog_now() { LANG=en_US.UTF-8 date "+%b %d %H:%M" ; } ;
## ↑↑ this ones failed when there are no log entries
```

Answer (score 1):

Dropping your date limits into `file1`

```
2018-04-12 14:44:00.000
2018-04-12 14:45:00.000
```

Then we can `awk` this

```
awk -F' |-|:' '
  {this=mktime($1" "$2" "$3" "$4" "$5" "$6);
     this=(this==-1)?last:this; last=this}
  NR==1{from=this;next}
  NR==2{to=this;next}
  this>=from&&this<=to' file1 file

2018-04-12 14:44:01.000 ERROR world
2018-04-12 14:44:03.000 INFO this is a multi-line log
NOTICE THIS LINE, this line is also part of the log
```

**Walkthrough**

Set up your field separators to split out the date/time elements

```
awk -F' |-|:'
```

Convert the first 6 fields to a timestamp

```
  '{this=mktime($1" "$2" "$3" "$4" "$5" "$6);
```

If this is a textfield without a stamp then take the last valid timestamp

```
     this=(this==-1)?last:this; last=this}
```

If this is the first record of the first file then store the timestamp in `from` and go get the `next` record

```
  NR==1{from=this;next}
```

Ditto for`to`

```
  NR==2{to=this;next}
```

Then just iterate over the second (log) file, check if the timestamp is in range and print if it is of interest

```
  this>=from&&this<=to' file1 file
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `sed`

```
sed -n '/2018-04-12 14:44:00.000/,/2018-04-12 14:45:00.000/p' log_file
```

It is worth noting this will only match the first instance, it just uses the dates as a delimiter to print between.

Similar thing can be achieved with `awk`:

```
awk '/^2018-04-12 14:44:00.000.*/,/2018-04-12 14:45:00.000.*/' log_file
```

Comment: @aLeX this is not a correct answer. What it does is print the line matching the pattern you inputted. If your log file has no matching line, it won't print anything even though theirs a line with log time of 14:44 - 14:45.

Comment: @WashichawbachaW thanks for your mention. I accepted this because of the usage of the comma(`,`) in `sed` and `awk`.